# Regex - How to validate a set of numbers delimited by "-"?

Tags: php, regex

i'm trying to figure out how to validate a number formated like that : XXXX or XXXX-XXXX

i tried

```
/^\d{4}(-{1}\d{4})?/i
```

but it validate only XXXX-XXXX format and not XXXX.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your regular expression looks correct (though the `{1}` does nothing, and you might want to anchor the expression to the end of the string, too, using a `$` at the end).  
Can you include a bit more of your code?

Comment: ^ And `i` does absolute nothing. If it's only numbers, we don't need to care about their case.

Comment: Your regex [works fine](http://regex101.com/r/iY4aR4) by the way. Add a `$` to the end, and you [only match the certain lines that match](http://regex101.com/r/jU2xX4):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No capture groups needed when doing validation:

```
^\d{4}(?:-\d{4})?$
^\/\ /\ /^\/\ /^^^
| | |  | | | | ||`-- end of string
| | |  | | | | |`-- previous is optional (non-capture group of `-` and 4 numbers 0-9)
| | |  | | | | `-- end of non-capture group
| | |  | | | `-- exactly 4 of previous (any number 0-9)
| | |  | | `-- any number 0-9
| | |  | `-- just `-`
| | |  `-- non-capture group
| | `-- exactly 4 of previous (any number 0-9)
| `-- any number 0-9
`-- start of string
```

Comment: Surely there's no need to *not* use a capturing group either? I can't imagine that it's better performance wise **not** to use one, as it'd have to go through additional logic (albeit, I might be wrong).

Comment: not using a capture group is more correct, but also makes the regex more complex for people that dont understand it

Comment: @h2ooooooo: There's additional logic in capturing, not the other way around. See [JavaScript capture vs non-capture](http://jsperf.com/regex-capture-vs-non-capture). Not sure if the same goes for PHP, but I would assume so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/\d{4}(-\d{4})?/
```

DEMO: http://regexr.com?356sf

Comment: No, it's not. `-` is only special in character classes (e.g. `[a-z]`).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one:

```
^\d{4}(-\d{4})?
```

Here: http://regexpal.com/

You can write the regex in the first area and test the numbers in the second area.

Works for 1234 and 1234-1234 (any numbers).